# Collectiong Anti-Join Results via Window Function?

Tags: postgresql, time-series, anti-join

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_table (
    c_id int4 NOT NULL,
    c_date_called int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t_table_un UNIQUE (c_id, c_date_called)
);
```

that stores distinct snapshots of data, with data as such:

```
INSERT INTO t_table (c_id, c_date_called) 
   VALUES
(1,9),
(2,9),
(3,9),
(4,9),
(5,9),
(1,12),
(2,12),
(3,12),
(5,12),
(1,17),
(3,17)
;
```

Against this table I can run an anti-join, comparing the `current` snapshot and one `previous` snapshot:

```
--EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE
SELECT prev.*
    FROM t_table AS prev
    LEFT JOIN t_table AS cur ON (prev.c_id = cur.c_id) AND cur.c_date_called = 17
    WHERE prev.c_date_called = 9
        AND cur.c_id IS NULL
        ;
```

returns the data I expect when finding the IDs not present in the current `c_date_called`:

```
c_id|c_date_called|
----+-------------+
   2|            9|
   4|            9|
```

But how do I apply the anti-join across multiple distinct `c_date_called` collecting the results and merging them as compared against the `current` `c_date_called`?

Well. Window functions with anti-joins.. yeah need help.

Comment: lots of questions.... Your anti-join selects records from prev (date = 9) which are not in cur (date = 17).  Why leave out result (5,9)?  Is max(c_date_called) always cur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to report the complete state of the `is`s in the snapshots, i.e. a snapshot with a *new* `id` not present in the previous snapshot resp. the `id` *removed*, i.e. not present in the *next* snapshot, you do not need an *anti-join*. Which you do not use in your example anyway.

First define the sequence of the snapshots using *integers* and flag the current snapshot

```
with snap as (
select distinct c_date_called from t_table),
snap2 as (
select  
  c_date_called,
  row_number() over(order by c_date_called) as snap_idx,
  c_date_called = max(c_date_called) over() is_current
from snap)
select * from snap2;

c_date_called|snap_idx|is_current|
-------------+--------+----------+
            9|       1|false     |
           12|       2|false     |
           17|       3|true      |
```

Than join this supporting information to your main table and add two attribuites based on the `lag` and `lead` window function of the *snapshot index* that identify if the previous / next snapshot with the given `id` is consecutive or if there is a gap. The logic should be pretty self-explained.

```
with snap as (
select distinct c_date_called from t_table),
snap2 as (
select  
  c_date_called,
  row_number() over(order by c_date_called) as snap_idx,
  c_date_called = max(c_date_called) over() is_current
from snap)
select 
 a.c_id, a.c_date_called, b.snap_idx, b.is_current,
 snap_idx != (1 + lag(snap_idx,1,0) over(partition by a.c_id order by snap_idx)) is_new,
 not (is_current) and snap_idx + 1 !=lead(snap_idx,1,0) over(partition by a.c_id order by snap_idx) is_removed
from t_table a
join snap2 b on a.c_date_called = b.c_date_called
order by 1,3;

c_id|c_date_called|snap_idx|is_current|is_new|is_removed|
----+-------------+--------+----------+------+----------+
   1|            9|       1|false     |false |false     |
   1|           12|       2|false     |false |false     |
   1|           17|       3|true      |false |false     |
   2|            9|       1|false     |false |false     |
   2|           12|       2|false     |false |true      |
   3|            9|       1|false     |false |false     |
   3|           12|       2|false     |false |false     |
   3|           17|       3|true      |false |false     |
   4|            9|       1|false     |false |true      |
   5|            9|       1|false     |false |false     |
   5|           12|       2|false     |false |true      |
   6|           12|       2|false     |true  |false     |
   6|           17|       3|true      |false |false     |
```

Note that I added `id` 6 that was introduced in the second snapshot to demonstrated this use case.

Comment: This gets to the heart of precisely what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I read this problem as:

I have a table t_table(c_id, c_date_called).
In this we have sets of data (c_id) per snapshot date (c_date_called).
The current snapshot which is the snapshot where c_date_called is highest.

Please give me an overview of all previous data (c_id) which was present in previous snapshots, but not in the current snapshot.

If so, this can be done simply without window functions:

```
select distinct 
    prev.c_id, 
    prev.c_date_called 
from 
    (select * from t_table where c_date_called not in (
        select max(c_date_called) from t_table)
    ) prev 
left join 
    (select * from t_table where c_date_called in (
        select max(c_date_called) from t_table)
    ) cur 
on 
    cur.c_id = prev.c_id 
where 
    cur.c_id isnull
```

Which gives the result:

[image]

Comment: If you want to have the difference between two upfollowing c_date_called (which is not in the example, because you skipped 12) instead of between all previous ones and the current one then you might need a window as Marmite Bomber shows in his solution.

Comment: Great query. Thank you for taking the time to construct it.
To find the spread of `id`s as they existed in the `previous` snapshots, this is useful

Comment: Yeah. Misunderstood your problem. Glad @Marmite Bomber could help you